# Finding the area of a set

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the area of the set $A=\{(x,y) \;|\; (x^2+y^2)^2 \leq x^3+y^3 \}$.
I tried doing it with a polar change of coordinates but I didn't manage to solve the integral that I came up with $\int (cos^3t+sin^3t)^2dt$.

Any ideas how can a handle this problem?

Comment: I think you have the right approach, now you just use trig. identities:  $\sin^3 t+\cos^3 t=(\sin t+\cos t)(1-\sin t \cos t)$ and so forth.

Comment: I think I did it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Write $x^2 + y^2 = r^2(\theta)$ on the left-hand-side and $x = r^3(\theta) \sin (\theta)$ and likewise for $y$ on the right-hand side.  Cancel an $r(\theta)$ to get a cubic.  The solutions are:

$$\left\{\sqrt[3]{\sin ^3(\theta )+\cos ^3(\theta )},-\sqrt[3]{-1} \sqrt[3]{\sin ^3(\theta )+\cos ^3(\theta )},(-1)^{2/3}
   \sqrt[3]{\sin ^3(\theta )+\cos ^3(\theta )}\right\}$$

Now integrate in radial coordinates, being sure to use the proper solutions.

[image]

Comment: How to find them? The equation is from fourth power.

Comment: Use computer algebra.  I get the answer directly in *Mathematica*.  Yes... it is long and complicated, but who cares?

Comment: But I want to solve it on a paper with a pen without a PC. Maybe there is an easier way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Tedious but basic.  $(cos^3(x)+ sin^3(x))^2= cos^6(x)+ 2cos^3(x)sin^3(x)+ sin^6(x)$.

To integrate $2cos^3(x)sin^3(x)dx$, write it as $2cos^2(x)sin^3(x)(cos(x)dx)= 2(1- sin^2(x))sin^3(x)(cos(x)dx)$ and let $u= sin(x)$so that $du= cos(x)dx$ and this becomes $2(1- u^2)u^3du= (2u^3- u^5)du$.

Both $cos^6(x)dx$ and $sin^6(x)dx$ have even powers of sine and cosine so you will want to use the "reduction formulas": $sin^2(x)= \frac{1- cos(2x)}{2}$ and $cos^2(x)= \frac{1+ cos(2x)}{2}$ to get odd powers.